# positive(?) definition of a transcendental number - as opposed to negative def. not an algebraic number

Tags: definition, transcendental-numbers, algebraic-numbers

Does this make sense? What's the formal definition of a transcendental number, but without saying it's *not* an algebraic number?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: That *is* the formal definition. What makes you think there’s another?

Comment: @TedShifrin I think that if you could define something by what it's *not*, you can also define it by what it *is*. And I think that side of the definition would be fun to think about.

Comment: OK, you tell me the definition of an irrational number.

Comment: Consider some $a \in F$, where $F$ is a field extension of $k$. Then $a$ is transcendental over $k$ if and only if there is a field homomorphism $f : k(x) \to F$ such that $f(x) = a$. Here, $k(x)$ is the field of rational functions on one variable with coefficients in $k$ - that is, the field of fractions of the integral domain $k[x]$.

Comment: Along the lines of @MarkSaving’s comment, just look at the polynomial ring $k[x]$. Evaluation at $\alpha\in F$ gives an isomorphism if and only if $\alpha$ is transcendental over $k$.

Comment: Depends on what you consider to be a "postive" definition. Does "a number that is not a root of any polynomial with integer coefficients" qualify ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no other definition.

By analogy, there is essentially no definition of "irrational" other than "not rational".

There is a philosophical point here. Any theorem that says that an assertion about $a$ is equivalent to $a$ being rational could be taken as the definition. So, for example, you could define "a is irrational" as "the continued fraction for $a$ never terminates".

If you had an analogous theorem about transcendentals you could use it as the definition. But that would probably not be clearer or better pedagogically.

Comment: Writing irrational numbers as an infinite fraction is kinda where I started from lol, so I still would like to know what that other definition would be.

Comment: I don't know of any "other definition" for transcendentals with that flavor. Perhaps someone will provide one, but I doubt it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the usual definition, rewritten to seem positive. For any nonzero polynomial $P$ with integer coefficients, denote
$A_P:= \{x \in {\mathbb R}: P(x) \ne 0\}$.
Then $\xi$ is transcedental iff it is in the intersection
$$\cap_{\{P \in{\mathbb Z}[x]\setminus\{0\}\}} \, A_{P}  \,.$$

Comment: This is cool, what did you rewrite from?

Comment: As you note, this _seems_ positive, but it is really just a fancy way to say the number is not the root of a polynomial with integer coefficients.

Comment: @Ethan Bolker   I agree.